# matchbox riddle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to solve the following riddle. Professor has one matchbox in either of his two pockets. With equal probability, he uses the matxchbox in the left or right. On finding an empty box, he replaces both matchboxes with new ones. Find the distribution of remaining matches after Professor finds an empty box.Each new box contains N matches.

Im actually really lost with starting this one. I'm not sure which 'common' distribution would fit this scenario. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the well known "Banach's matchbox problem." The solution [can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly consider the random variable R: the time of the (N+1)th using of the right box. R's distribution is negative binomial of order N+1 and parameter 1/2. If R isn't greater than 2N+1, then the number of remaining matches is 2N+1-R. This is my hint.